# Iterated logarithm Big-O complexity

Tags: time-complexity, big-o, logarithm, iterated-logarithm

I have 2 doubts:-

1) Is (log* n)^n = O((logn)!) ?

2) Which is bigger, log(log* n) or log*(logn) ?

Comment: It is known as iterated logarithm ! You can check here :- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_logarithm

Comment: -.- it's log star and not a multiplication. I am sorry :) It was hard to notice.

Comment: I know it's hard to notice. That's why I mentioned it in the title of the question. Can you help me with this question ?

Comment: I am not sure why I am receiving down votes. Did I ask something wrong ?

Comment: You showed 0 efforts. (I didn't Down voted you).

Answer (score 5):

For 2), you have `log*(log n) = log*(n)-1`. Then let `m = log*(n)`. You have `m-1 > log(m)` for sufficiently large `m`.

---

**Hint**:

For 1), let `m = log*(n)`. Then the LHS is `m^n`, and the RHS is the factorial of the logarithm of an exponential tower of height `m`, i.e. the factorial of an exponential tower of height `m-1`.

Even disregarding the factorial, an exponential tower should grow much faster than a power.

Comment: From the very definition of `log*`.

Comment: Can you help me with the 1st problem please ?

Comment: I think you are considering RHS as (log* n )!. It's (log n)!

Comment: @Zephyr: o, I am not.

Comment: Just let me know if I am correct . In 1st case, we can consider log*n as approximately a constant (let it be k) . Now k^n = O(n!). So for very large n, k^n = O((logn)!). Hence (log *n)^n = O((log n)!). Am I correct?

Comment: @Zephyr: in asymptotic computations, you may not consider log*n as constant.